# Can I submit the same APK with different package name and display name to Google Play?

Tags: android

I have opened a Google Play developer account 4 days ago and submitted my first app. It has passed over 60 hours since submission; yet the app is nowhere to be found in Google Play. Neither in the search results; nor at the direct link. (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lostaliens.crocusgames.lostaliens)
I have opened a ticket to the support and in the mean time resubmitted my APK. (Uploaded to the production, not beta or alpha)

Now I wonder if it is OK to submit the same APK with different package name and display name to Google Play. I just want to see if it will get through. I will unpublish the other one, once one of them actually goes in the market. However, I have no idea if this is against the TOS or something. Obviously, I don't want to be blocked/banned from the market.

I know this is complicated; but as an inexperienced developer; I need all the help I can get.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you can , go ahead and upload !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per **GooglePlay** guidelines, you can't upload the same `.apk` twice without changing either the package name or `Version Code`.

When you upload a `.apk` to **GooglePlay**, it checks whether the corresponding package name already exists in the market. If it doesn't exist, you can upload it otherwise you can't. If you want to upload an update of the same app, then you have to increment the `Version Code` in the <s>manifest</s> app level's `build.gradle` file create a signed app, and then upload it.

If you change the package name as you have mentioned, **GooglePlay** will treat it as a totally different application. So you can upload it without any problem.

for reference

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en&ref_topic=3450986

Comment: they will treat as different app.... oh i see then....