# unable to sign in to google play game services

Tags: android, google-play-games, sign, developer-console

I am creating an application which need **google play game sign in**. I created app in developer console and application is running properly. now I have to change the package name of the game but I can't delete since I already publish that game.
How to handle this situation. Help me.
**I want to add my application as a new game and delete the old game since I don't need THE old one** I am new to android and google developer console is very confusing. please Help

com.wordpress.applica.quizz   **my old application package**
com.wordpress.applica.qui       **my new application package**

but they both are same application

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669911/how-to-delete-the-published-app-from-developer-console-android), you can't delete app from account. Just make them unpublish. However, be noted that it will be still visible in account ie main server but in playstore, it will not be available.

> You can delete an app anytime before it is published.
>
> After it has been published, it "owns" its unique packagename forever in the Google PlayStore app naming hierarchy:
>
> com.yourdomain.yourapp
>
> There is no "deleting" this packagename after publication. That would cause mayhem.

If you want to add your application as new game, you may upload it but just make sure the package name is different with the first app uploaded. [GooglePlay will treat it as a totally different application.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261411/can-i-submit-the-same-apk-with-different-package-name-and-display-name-to-google) So you can upload it without any problem.

Comment: i am unable to sign in to google play game service from my new application which i created